# Is it legal to migrate data from old software to new software?

Tags: software, data

I'm wondering about the legality of migrating data between two competitor software, particularly for this purpose. Customer buys new software and want to migrate their old data.

Is it legal for the company of the new software to get a copy of the data of the old software (all files, and a copy of the database) from the customer and by the means of trial and error figure how the data are stored and migrate them to the new software?

Comment: Depends on where you are, and if it becomes a civil or criminal case. Reverse-engineering, even by trial and error, might violate the TOS your customer signed.

Answer (score 2):

Generally, yes (at least under U.S. law).

Typically, you are the owner of the data or licensed to use it, if it is copyrightable at all. It is less clear with copyrightable work on an online platform where the TOS purports to give the online platform the copyright to the data.